# boost python vector of map .. (of structs) .. no luck

Tags: python, vector, boost, struct, maps

Trying to expose a vector of maps (key being strings and value being struct objects) with following types:

```
// boost includes ..

struct MyStruct {
  double a;
  vector<double> vec;
  bool operator==(const MyStruct& other) {return false;}
  bool operator!=(const MyStruct& other) {return true;}
};

typedef map<string, MyStruct>      MyMap;

typedef vector<MyStruct>           MyVec;
typedef vector<MyMap>              MyVec2;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(_axstatistics)
{

    py::class_<MyStruct>("MyStruct")
        .def_readwrite("a", &MyStruct::a)
        .def_readwrite("vec", &MyStruct::vec)
        ;

    py::class_<MyMap>("MyMap")
        .def(map_indexing_suite<MyMap>());

    py::class_<MyVec>("MyVec")
        .def(vector_indexing_suite<MyVec>());

// uncomment and boum
//    py::class_<MyVec2>("MyVec2")
//        .def(vector_indexing_suite<MyVec2>());

}
```

This works for `MyVec` but not for `MyVec2`, I get an almost unreadable compilation error to me..

Anyone have an idea or has experience with such a pattern ?

Thx in advance..

Answer (score 0):

got it running by also defining `==` operators on the `MyMap` and `MyVec2` classes.